# Scheduling load with a round robin algorithm?

Tags: c#, round-robin

I need to write a round robin algorithm to schedule load to n endpoints?

So if I have servers A, B and C

I wanted to make sure to round-robin through them for each request I get. How do I do this in C#?

Comment: Will it be constant load or you want even distribution of load?

Comment: I think 'round robin' indicates there is no attempt to evenly distribute the load.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just for the record, definition of round robin:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling

Just use a queue.  Take one off of the top, use it and put it back.  This ensures that the most recent one used will always be the last one to be picked up.

```
Queue<Server> q = new Queue<Server>();

//get the next one up
Server s = q.DeQueue();


//Use s;


//put s back for later use.
q.Enqueue(s);
```

Link to the queue class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx

Comment: I would challenge a person who said he wanted to implement round robin to figure out if they really mean round robin.

Comment: It's used in server load distribution all the time.

Comment: When using this pattern, it might be worthwhile to immediately enqueue the server before using it (or putting the enqueue in a finally block).  That way, any exceptions thrown during "using" the server won't possibly result in the server being removed from the rotation entirely.

Comment: this should be wrapped in a class

Comment: Wouldn't a linkedlist be better than a queue? no need to re-queue items, just restart from head :)

Answer (score 8):

Same idea as ebpower, but focussing on what is the next item rather than what is the index of the next item.

```
public class RoundRobinList<T>
{
    private readonly IList<T> _list;
    private readonly int _size;
    private int _position;

    public RoundRobinList(IList<T> list)
    {
        if (!list.Any())
            throw new NullReferenceException("list");

        _list = new List<T>(list);
        _size = _list.Count;            
    }

    public T Next()
    {
        if (_size == 1)
            return _list[0];

        Interlocked.Increment(ref _position);
        var mod = _position % _size;
        return _list[mod];
    }
}
```

Comment: pass IEnumerable<T> to constructor and record mod before Incrementing _position, and this is money.

Comment: `Interlocked.Increment` will reach `int.MaxValue` in very high load scenarios.
In that case, it handles the overflow condition and returns `int.MinValue` as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netframework-4.7.1) and this code will throw an `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` while accessing the array because of the negative index. 
A simple check can handle it:
 `
 ...
Interlocked.Increment(ref _position);
if(_position == Int32.MinValue)
{
    Interlocked.Exchange(ref _position, 0);
}
...
`

Comment: Alternative implementation that resets the position when the end of the list is reached: https://gist.github.com/randyburden/251f0514f893013d711da1b4e395aaa5

Answer (score 2):

If your endpoints are accessed through a List or Array, you only need to increment an index in a circular fashion:

```
public class RoundRobinIndex
{
    volatile int index = 0;
    int count;

    public int Next
    {
        get
        {
            if (index == count)
            {
                index = 0;
            } 
            return index++;
        }
    }

    public RoundRobinIndex(int countArg)
    {
        count = countArg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using that will cause an IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: @IBootstrap - It does Not cause an IndexOutOfRangeException. Have you actually tested it?

Comment: Next can also be achieved using: (index + 1) % count;